# Litecoin litecore-lib receive UTXO and current balance

Tags: transactions, litecoin, utxo, bitcore, node.js

I have coded `NodeJS` script for `bitcoin` for send all balance from by address to some other one. Now I want to do this for the `litecoin`. For `bitcoin` I have used [bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib) and [bitcore-explorers](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers) libs to do that.

For `litecoin` I have found forked and adopted lib [litecore-lib](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore-lib/), but I can't found solution to receive `UTXO` data for some LTC address like I do it in case of `bitcoin`:

```
var Insight = require("bitcore-explorers").Insight;
var insight = new Insight(network);
insight.getUnspentUtxos(sourceAddress, function (error, utxos) {
    // determine balance, fee and sign transaction
}
```

How can I do this for `litecoin`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the `request` library to manually retrieve information from the insight API. I also used the `litecore-lib` library to create the transaction.

```
var Litecoin = require("litecore-lib");
var request = require("request");

//manually hit an insight api to retrieve utxos of address
function getUTXOs(address) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      uri: 'https://insight.litecore.io/api/addr/' + address + '/utxo',
      json: true
    },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) reject(error);
        resolve(body)
      }
    )
  })
}

//manually hit an insight api to broadcast your tx
function broadcastTX(rawtx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      uri: 'https://insight.litecore.io/tx/send',
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        rawtx
      }
    },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) reject(error);
        resolve(body.txid)
      }
    )
  })
}

//your private key and address here
var privateKey = PrivateKey.fromWIF('YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE');
var address = privateKey.toPublicKey().toAddress();

getUTXOs(address)
  .then((utxos) => {

    let balance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < utxos.length; i++) {
      balance +=utxos[i]['satoshis'];
    } //add up the balance in satoshi format from all utxos

    var fee = 1500; //fee for the tx
    var tx = new Litecoin.Transaction() //use litecore-lib to create a transaction
      .from(utxos)
      .to('TO_ADDRESS', balance - fee) //note: you are sending all your balance AKA sweeping
      .fee(fee)
      .sign(privateKey)
      .serialize();

    return broadcastTX(tx) //broadcast the serialized tx
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // txid
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  })
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecore-explorers like this:

```
var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
var insight = new explorers.Insight(https://insight.litecore.io', 'mainnet');

insight.getUtxos('mgBmKKZEkK...', function(err, utxos) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle errors...
  } else {
    // Do something with utxos
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the module what you may require
https://www.npmjs.com/package/litecore-explorers

Comment: This package is the result of my attempts to adopt `bitcore-explorers` package for litecoin, so it doesn't work! Don't try to use it!